# How can we change the complete look and feel of Sharepoint Portal?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

by Default there are Themes, I don't Like those. `How can I modify It completely and make a professional website`. I have found same Questions on `this blog` but all for MOSS2007. I am working on `Sharepoint 2010`

Comment: These type of questions should go on http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

The way I modify sharepoint, is as I do with almost every other CMS out there combined with the power of asp .Net (Remember that as CMS' go sharepoint is a poor solution if the only thing you want is a portal. Sharepoint is first and foremost a [BI Solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_intelligence)).

When you edit your site in sharepoint designer (Site Action -> Edit in sharepoint designer) you can see a whole lot of options.

Here you can change the default masterpage to accomodate the look and feel of your site. You will do most of the hiding stuff here (those you don't want to be seen giving them the visibility=false attribute). Here you can also include a new CSS (place it in site assets) where you can override already existing css files.

From this point on, you will be able to add web pages to the site, that will conform to the masterpage, and thus you can use all the sharepoint power (web parts and even embedded html code) keeping the look and feel you have implemented on your master page.

So what you need to do is:

1. Modify master page in sharepoint designer
2. Add css files in site assets and include them in your masterpage
3. Add any other aspx pages or custom web parts that you will refer to in the sharepoint site
4. Create web pages with sharepoint assets, web parts or custom code
5. Enable anonymous access for the people you want to view your portal without authenticating (Bear in mind that there are some sharepoint controls that can only be viewed by logged in users)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of customizing it.

My perfered way is CSS.

1. Add reference to a custom css in master page using feature
2. Modify the look and feel by modifying sharepoint out-of-box CSS

Following resources gives all the details of SharePoint 2010 css classes.

http://sp2010notes.wordpress.com/sharepoint-2010-css-chart/
http://sharepointexperience.com/csschart/csschart.html

I hope it helps.

Cheers.
Rajendra Shekhawat